# locate package libffi6 - Kivy app to APK Colab

Tags: python, kivy, apk, google-colaboratory

I am using Kivy to develop mobile applications, but run into issues when converting main.py to an .apk file.

I have tried various approaches, all without succes. The closest I have gotten is to use this colab notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1b9gMzs6XAtxCtahxei4N0fWZk7xiPlVw?usp=sharing#scrollTo=elrRZQ-fHUF1

After running all the cells I do obtain an apk file, but the app crashes on startup.

I suspect the issue has to do with cell5 in the colab notebook:
`!sudo apt-get install build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev openssl libgdbm-dev libgdbm-compat-dev liblzma-dev libreadline-dev libncursesw5-dev libffi-dev uuid-dev libffi6`
I get the following output:

```
 - Reading package lists... Done 
 - Building dependency tree        
 - Reading state information... Done 
 - E: Unable to locate package libffi6
```

Why am I getting this error, and how can I solve it?

My main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class HelloWorld(App):
    def build(self):
        main_window = Button(text="hello world")
        return main_window

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = HelloWorld()
    app.run()
```

and in the buildozer.spec file, I have added requirements: python3,kivy==2.0.0,kivymd,pillow

I tried following all tutorials I could find. But even if I copy their steps exactly, I still get different output in the google colab cells. I also tried to obtain a logcat, but I did not manage because I work with kivy and do not use android studio.

Comment: adb & logcat is essential when developing Android apps, without you are more or less blind. Therefore I strongly recommend to install at last minimal adb from Android SDK. Also check your Linux distributions package manger, often it already provides an adb version that should be sufficient for adb and logcat.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `!pip install cython==0.29.19` to `!pip install cython==0.29.32`, the latest cython version is `!pip install cython==0.29.34` so you can try either of these. If that doesn't work the only way to know why the app keeps crashing on startup is to use a logcat.

Answer (score 0):

```
E: Unable to locate package libffi6
```

you can do:

```
  !sudo apt-get install libffi7
  !sudo apt-get install build-essential libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 bzip2 libbz2-dev zlib1g-dev libssl-dev openssl libgdbm-dev libgdbm-compat-dev liblzma-dev libreadline-dev libncursesw5-dev libffi-dev uuid-dev libffi7
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was also experiencing the same issue using the same colab notebook.

To get it working, edit the requirements in your buildozer.spec file to look something like:

```
requirements = android, hostpython3==3.9.6, python3==3.9.6,kivy==2.1.0,kivymd==1.1.1,camera4kivy,gestures4kivy
```

Then, use the below variant of the colab notebook to build the app. It should build the apk file without any issues, i've already tested it multiple times for different complex builds.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11wLisDBglKDLZlSHydoQtSEcUTQXhyJ-#scrollTo=sbL2gpx8HZ7t